# ReactPDF: parsing html string to html and displaying

Tags: reactjs, html-to-pdf, react-pdf

I am currently parsing the HTML string to HTML the problem is when I am trying to display it to a pdf. I am using  [PDFDownloadLink](https://react-pdf.org/components#pdfdownloadlink)

this is the array of items I have to parse

```
const unit = [
{
_id: 1,
text: '<p>hello there</p>',
},
{
_id: 2,
text: '<h1>hello there</h1>',
}
{
_id: 3,
text: '<p>hello there</p><br/> <p>Hello World</p>',
}
]
```

JSX

```
(units.map((unit) => {
 let text = <p>hello</p>
                  if (unit.text) {
                    const parser = new DOMParser()
                    const doc = parser.parseFromString(unit.text, 'text/html')
                    // doc.body.firstChild

                  }

                  return (
                      {/* <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: unit.text }} /> */}
                      <Text>
                        <div>
                          {text}
                        </div>
                      </Text>
                  )

})
```

When I set the text to be `doc.body.firstChild`

I get this error message:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object HTMLParagraphElement]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Comment: I tried to dangerouslySetInnerHTML and that came back blank with ReactPDF

Comment: tried a different approach  `const objCopy = { ...unit }
                    objCopy.text = doc.body.firstChild
                    text = objCopy` this  sadly didnt work

Comment: **got this error message:** scheduler.development.js:171 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object HTMLParagraphElement]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who has the same issue in the future, I found a package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf-html) as it reads it renders HTML into reactpdf